# How can I programmatically get a device's serial number via HTML?

Tags: html, mobile

In an HTML5 application, I need to uniquely identify the device (phone, tablet, desktop, what have you) so that I can send appropriate data to it from the db. My searches have not yielded solutions, so I thought I'd try real people.

Thanks!

Comment: sessions might be an option. I don't think this can be done with HTML alone though.

Comment: I think the question is not completely clear. Do you want to recognize what *type* of device your user is using (-> Smartphone, Tablet, Desktop, ..) *or* do you want to identify each device unique (-> User 1's smartphone with id 12, User 2's desktop with id 56)?

Comment: _“I need to uniquely identify the device […] so that I can send appropriate data to it from the db”_ – that’s an unusual approach; normally, you try to identify _users_, because what individual content they might get served depends on _them_, and not the device they are (currently) using. So what’s your actual use case that would require handling this differently?

Comment: @CBroe We have a requirement to associate a selected device with location in the factory. While it is so associated, it gets data fed to it related to the function at that location. At a later time the device can be un-associated from the first and then tied to another location. So, it is not User dependent but rather more location dependent.

Comment: @codezombie The latter - ideally we would "read" the serial number of the device (or some other unique identifier)

Comment: @WillAutio - I have posted an answere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use `cookies`. With the usage of cookies you can give each device a **unique**, by yourself created `ID`, which enables you to identify each device. If you are not familiar with the concept of cookies in the web, a good point to start learning about them in general is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

If you do know *what* a cookie is, but do not know *how* to implement them into `PHP`or `Javascript`, a good point to start is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php) (for `PHP`) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) (for `Javascript`).

If you have already read these articles, but do not know *how to start* implementing `cookies` into your code, here is a snippet for `PHP`:

```
// check whether the device is already known; a cookie is already set
if(isset($_COOKIE["deviceIdentifier"])) {
    // there is already a cookie set; we know the device
    echo "This is the Device: ".$_COOKIE["deviceIdentifier"];
} else {
    // there is no cookie set; a new device has connected
    $dIdentifier = md5(time());
    // set a new cookie for the device
    setcookie("deviceIdentifier",$dIdentifier,time() * 2);
    echo "A new Device has ben recognized, it is now linked with the ID: ".$dIdentifier;
}
```

---

One comment to your approach of *using the devices serial number* : This is not that easy and should not be seen as a good approach as the creation of `ID`s by yourself is far more easier and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a randomly generated ID in a cookie and/or JavaScript's localStorage and use that to uniquely identify the device.